# What does this mean 'libc is strange'? I created a symbolic link and then i got this message

Tags: 18.04

I get this message when i try to install dotDefender:
libc is strange: '/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6'

Comment: `readlink -f /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6`

Comment: I tried that. It didn't work. Is there anything else I can do? I am still getting the same message:  libc is strange: '/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6'

Comment: Show the output.

Comment: Isn't this the output? @nobody I ran this on the terminal: "./dotDefender-3.8-5.Linux.i386.deb.bin" and it gives this as the output:
./dotDefender-3.8-5.Linux.i386.deb.bin: libc is strange: '/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6'

Comment: `apt-cache policy libc6` please.  and `dpkg --print-architecture` also `dpkg --print-foreign-architectures`

Comment: @nobody I get this: apt-cache policy libc6
libc6:
  Installed: 2.27-3ubuntu1
  Candidate: 2.27-3ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 2.27-3ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

Comment: dpkg --print-architecture
amd64

Comment: dpkg --print-foreign-architectures
i386

Comment: can you give me a link for dotdefender? Never heard about this. `sudo apt install --reinstall libc6`

Comment: Here is the link: http://www.applicure.com/downloads/3.85/linux/dotDefender-3.8-5.Linux.i386.deb.bin.gz

Comment: I ran the command in the terminal and it re-installs what it's supposed to but I am getting the same error.

Comment: I googled and got this site: http://www.applicure.com/download-latest. Then I downloaded the 64 bit version for debian and gave it executable permission. However upon running i got a message that says :                                                               /tmp/dotDefender/installer.perl: Unknown exit status='1' (func=func_welcome)